# erro em progama

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def trianguloPascal(n):
    lista = [[1],[1,1]]
    for i in range(1,n):
        linha = [1]
        for j in range(0,len(lista[i])-1):
            linha += [ lista[i][j] + lista[i][j+1] ]
        linha += [1]
        lista += [linha]
    return lista

n = input("Digite o número de linhas para o triângulo de Pascal: ")
resultado = trianguloPascal(n)

for i in range(len(resultado)):
    print(resultado[i])
```

Comment: Por favor clique em [edit] acima, selecione todo o código e clique no botão `{}` do editor para formatar corretamente. E por favor explique qual é o problema do código e qual é a sua dúvida.

Comment: João, adicione sempre um título que acrescente conteúdo a sua dúvida e descreva o seu problema de forma detalhada no escopo do post, assim fica mais fácil para receber ajuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você se esqueceu de converter a entrada do usuário de string para inteiro:

```
resultado = trianguloPascal(int(n))
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/Tb9T7m)